# How to select a radio then submit form with jQuery in vBulletin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, userscripts, vbulletin

I am working on a userscript that injects my own JS into the head (this part works). I am utilizing the site's already in-place jQuery.

I am a moderator on a vBulletin forum. I move and close A LOT of threads. I figured it would save me insurmountable amount of time if I reduced the total number of clicks I make by 2 clicks per thread.

Using `.append()` I've added my own `<td>` with a "quick access" `<a>` tag.
What I would like to happen is for when I click the `<a>` tag (Close or Move) it selects the appropriate option in the thread tools form (which as far as I can tell is working the way I have it coded) and then submit the form as if I had hit the Perform Actions button.

My current code is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var topbar = $('#threadtools').closest('tr');
    var newTool = '<td><a href="#" id="newClose" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><b>Close</b></a></td>' +
                    '<td><a href="http://google.com" id="newMove"><b>Move</b></a></td>'; // Google for testing purposes I wanted to make sure preventDefault was working
    topbar.append(newTool);

    $('#newClose').click(function() { 
        alert();
    });
    $('#newMove').click(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        //var form = $('input[name$="threadadminform"]');  // select form by name
        var button = $('input[value="Perform Action"]');   // select button by name


        var closeradio = $('#ao_oct');
        var moveradio = $('#ao_mvt');
        var copyradio = $('#ao_cpt');
        var editradio = $('#ao_edt');
        var deleteradio = $('#ao_dlt');
        var stickradio = $('#ao_sut');
        var mergeradio = $('#ao_mgt');
        var redirectradio = $('#ao_rrd');

        closeradio.removeAttr('checked');
        copyradio.removeAttr('checked');
        editradio.removeAttr('checked');
        deleteradio.removeAttr('checked');
        stickradio.removeAttr('checked');
        mergeradio.removeAttr('checked');
        redirectradio.removeAttr('checked');

        moveradio.attr('checked', 'checked');
        button.trigger();
    });
});
```

As you can see I am currently trying to `.trigger()` the submit button, this does not work.
I have also tried `.submit()` on the form var I declared at the top, this also does not work.

How can I get this to submit as it would if I clicked the button and take me to the next appropriate page?

Comment: .submit should would, are you sure you're using it on the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trigger needs a minimum of event, so you need to pass button.trigger('click') so that it will be able to perform the click event.

Sample demo of what you are trying to achieve is [at](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), take a look at two button example at the above location.

hope this helps.

Comment: Such a small oversight. I LOVE YOU!